# Inlining an array comparison function

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following array comparison function:

```
function cmp_arrs(a, b) {
    if (a === b) return true;
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;
    for (let i=0; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i] != b[i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

How could I convert this -- particular the `for` loop -- into a single-line javascript Arrow function. So far I have:

```
const cmp_arrs2 = (a,b) => (a === b) || ((a.length === b.length) && (<forLoop?>))
```

My current approach is stringifying it and seeing if that works but that seems a bit crude/wrong:

```
const cmp_arrs2 = (a,b) => (a === b) || ((a.length === b.length) 
      && (Object.values(a).toString() == Object.values(b).toString()))
```

Comment: why not `JSON.stringify(a)===JSON.stringify(b)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a higher-order function such as [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). In order for `.every()` to return `true`, the callback must return `true` for each item, if it returns `false` for any item then `.every()` will result in `false`. You can use the second argument of the callback to obtain the index `i` to grab the corresponding element from the array `b`:

```
const cmp_arrs2 = (a,b) => 
  a === b || a.length === b.length && a.every((elem, i) => elem === b[i]);
```

`&&` has higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `||`, so the grouping `()` can also be omitted if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following:

```
// Create a Separate Function
const cmp_loop = (a, b) => {
for (let i=0; i < a.length; i++)
        if (a[i] != b[i]) return false;
 return true;
}

// Now make a single line function
const cmp_array = (a, b) => (a === b) || ((a.length === b.length) && cmp_loop(a, b))

// You can also do this:
const cmp_array_2 = (a, b) => (a === b) || ((a.length === b.length) && a.reduce((equal, current, index) => !equal ? equal : current === b[index], true))

// Another quick way (If you are sure that the elements in both arrays are on same positions or indexes):
const cmp_array_3 = (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
```